# How can I extract from an array of arrays all the arrays that have the same value in their first field?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, higher-order-functions

The following function elegantly finds duplicates in 1-dimensional arrays:

```
    const findDuplicates  = (dataArray) => {
      const duplicates = dataArray.filter((e, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(e) !== index);
      return (duplicates);
    };
```

When I send it (for example) this array
['123456', '787877', '763223', '787877', '854544'] it returns ['787877'].

What I need is something similar that works for a 2-d array so (for instance) inputting

```
    [ 
      ['123456', 'Smith'],
      ['787877',  'Jones'],
      ['763223', 'Waldo'],
      ['787877',  'Quagmire'],
      ['854544',  'Miller']
    ]
```

returns

[['787877',  'Jones'], ['787877',  'Quagmire']]

(To be clear, I'm only interested in whether the 1st field of each sub-array is a dupe.)

Comment: You can use the same method, however you'll need `.findIndex()` (note that your only problem is finding the index of an array element that matches a condition, always remove everything irrelevant from your question to find existing solutions way easier)

Comment: I am not familiar with js yet, but the easy way is to add a helper function that will transform your array into a 1D array then use your function.

Comment: @benlyazid No, an 1d array won't work

Comment: @Bergi but you only have to check for the first field in your 2d  array ?

Comment: @benlyazid Oh you mean using a 1d array for the `indexOf` check but keeping the 2d array for the `filter`?

Comment: @Bergi no what I mean is to extract data from your 2d array  and transform it to 1d array like the first example you give

Comment: @benlyazid You mean the example the OP gave? But that doesn't work, they want a 2d result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const findDuplicates = (dataArray) => {
  const duplicates = dataArray.filter((e, index, arr) => {
    return arr.some((val, i) => (index !== i && val[0] === e[0]))
  })
  return (duplicates);
};

const result = findDuplicates([
  ['123456', 'Smith'],
  ['787877', 'Jones'],
  ['763223', 'Waldo'],
  ['787877', 'Quagmire'],
  ['854544', 'Miller']
])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object and use a boolean values to indicae duplicates. Then filter the array.

```js
const
    findDuplicates = data => {
        const
            keys = data.reduce((r, [v]) => {
                r[v] = r[v] !== undefined;
                return r;
            }, {});

        return data.filter(([v]) => keys[v]);
    },
    data = [['123456', 'Smith'], ['787877', 'Jones'], ['763223', 'Waldo'], ['787877', 'Quagmire'], ['854544', 'Miller']],
    result = findDuplicates(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```